# Is this a bug from the PHP Exception system?

Tags: php, exception, behavior

I have:

```
<?php

    try 
    {
        throw new Exception('Debes iniciar sesión para esto.', 1); // This is a null exception.
        throw new Exception('Debes iniciar sesion para esto.', 1); // This is not a null exception.
    }
    catch (Exception $ex1) 
    {
        echo 'Message: ' . $ex1->getMessage();
    }
```

When I throw the first exception it results null!! and I can't get the message when handling it! but for some reason if I remove the accent it throws the message correctly.

What could it be? a bug? (if you don't believe me, try it yourself)

Comment: Maybe a problem with [encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220909/php-5-4-throw-exception-cant-see-message-with-iso-8859-1-encoded-string-messa) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/MDs4NB. You're missing your echo statement to make the string and error message print out:

```
try 
{
    throw new Exception('Debes iniciar sesión para esto.', 1); // This is a null exception.
    throw new Exception('Debes iniciar sesion para esto.', 1); // This is not a null exception.
}
catch (Exception $ex1) 
{
    echo 'Message: ' . $ex1->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for typo (it was a quick snipet) but it's weird, i can't see the message in my enviroment (5.3.5)

Comment: Why's this upvoted? The missing `echo` was probably a typo in the original question (update: [it was](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22233022/revisions))

Comment: But as the fiddle shows this code works. So it isn't a bug with the code.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, it has nothing to do with PHP, as John Conde said, the thing was that I forgot the use of json_encode with the exception, and json_encode doesn't like non-utf8 characters, so I had something like:

```
try 

{

 throw new Exception('Debes iniciar sesión para esto.', 1);

}

catch (Exception $ex1) 

{

 echo json_encode(array('message' => $ex1->getMessage()));

}
```

So, when json_encode detects non-utf8 data it will return NULL, so in order to fix this issue we have to explicity encode the data to utf8 before getting the json like this:

```
json_encode(array('message' => utf8_encode('Canción.')));
```

The result will generate a JSON with hex characters formated (i.e \x00), with their respective ASCII code. Sorry for telling it was PHP issue when it was a bad of mine. However, I'll accept the John's answer because he answered correctly and he deserves the credit, but I will also leave mine to provide the real cause of the problem.