# php 5.4 charset for Exception

Tags: php, php-5.4

In php 5.4 my code dont work properly. I use cyrillic charset. In short:

```php
throw new Exception('Сообщение');
```

will output:

> Fatal error: in test.php ...

although the result would be:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message ...

If I dont use cyrillic characters, the result is Ok. Moreover, if I run this code in 5.3, I'll get the proper result. I. e. if I use cyrillic, the result message is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There are reported issues with non utf-8 chars in exceptions. Try converting the message to utf-8 like so:

```
throw new Exception(utf8_encode('Сообщение'));
```

if that does not work then try the following:

```
$message = 'Сообщение';
$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8');
throw new Exception($message);
```

**-- EDIT --**

The actual problem is not that the exception message is not stored, but rather - the exception is not displayed properly. In PHP 5.3, xdebug is not turned on by default and in PHP 5.4, it is. xdebug is set to display everything in UTF-8 and your message is probably encoded in some other charset, thus the message not being rendered correctly.

If you scroll to the bottom of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) page, you will find a single comment referring to this problem.

PHP themselves tracked this issue on [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63426&edit=2)

[This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220909/php-5-4-throw-exception-cant-see-message-with-iso-8859-1-encoded-string-messa) is also related to the same issue.

You might be able to get away by setting the xdebug encoding to a non utf-8 charset. Please [read the xdebug manual regarding this](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#feature-names)

Comment: The point is that I have already a big project, so unfortunately it's not a solution for me. Probably I'm looking for a setting that will make my code working duly.

Comment: Please can you give a link to these issues?

Comment: Edited the answer with some references and a better explanation

Comment: killneel, thank you! But does it mean that if I don't use xdebug, I should to add it to php and configure it to use cyrillic charset by default?

Comment: That could probably help if all your source files are encoded in a cyrillic charset.

Comment: Yes, almost all is in cp1251. But there are files in utf. Only this two charsets.

Comment: And now I'm thinking of converting all of project files to UTF :)

Comment: ISO-8859-1 cannot represent any Cyrillic characters, so both your `mb` conversion and the equivalent `utf8_encode` *cannot* work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the charset specified by OP. Also, my answer covers content other than charset conversion. Please read the entire thread before downvoting.